# How to access attributes in envoy configuration

Tags: envoyproxy

I am trying to set up a front proxy in envoy where I pass the path in a header (`test-header` in below example).

```
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service/1"
                request_headers_to_add:
                - header:
                   key: "test-path"
                   value: request.path
                route:
                  cluster: service1
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service/2"
                route:
                  cluster: service2
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
```

I see there is a `request.path` attribute in envoy https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/advanced/attributes

How can I pass this value to yaml config?

Comment: I am struggling with issues like this all the time. It would be so nice if they would add a simple yaml (or JSON) example to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, the [attributes](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.27.0/intro/arch_overview/advanced/attributes) are:

> only exposed to CEL runtime in [RBAC filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.27.0/intro/arch_overview/security/rbac_filter#arch-overview-rbac), as well as Wasm extensions via `get_property` ABI method.

So in your case, you can't really use them directly.

To get the path in your `test-path` header, you can instead use [HTTP command operators](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.27.0/configuration/observability/access_log/usage#config-access-log-command-operators) in your [custom request/response headers](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.27.0/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#custom-request-response-headers):

```yaml
routes:
- match:
    prefix: "/service/1"
  request_headers_to_add:
  - header:
      key: "test-path"
      value: "%REQ(:path)%"
```

This has been tested with Envoy 1.27.0.